# What is the probability in any s-of-a king in n cards?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

What is the probability of getting any s of a kind (let's say 3 of a kind) when dealt n cards (let's say 13) of a standar deck?
I have calculated the probability of getting a specific set of 3 of a kind (i.e. 3 Kings) which is $ \frac{\left(
\begin{array}{c}
4\\
3
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
52-3\\
13-3
\end{array}
\right)}{\left(
\begin{array}{c}
52\\
13
\end{array}
\right)}
$ (please correct me if I'm wrong).

However, what I am trying to find is the probability of getting any s of a kind, and furthermore the probability of getting any s of a kind greater than one specific value.

Comment: Should a hand with 4 of a kind be included in the count? What about 3 kings and 3 tens in the same hand (if $n\ge2s$)? Should that contŕibute one or two or none at all to the count?

Comment: Yes, a hand with 4 of a kind is included in the count. I should have said at least one "s of a kind". 
(3 kings and 3 tens should contribute one to the count).

Comment: @anitaV: The numerator of your formula is wrong. If you want exactly $3$ kings then the number is $\binom43\binom{52-4}{13-3}$, and if you also want to count the $4$ kings possibilities, then you need to _add_ $\binom44\binom{52-4}{13-4}$ to that (see the answer by Hagen).

Comment: [s-of-a king](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=sofa%20king)

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen: Are you sure about that? I mean, the $4$ King possibilities isn't it included in the number $ 
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
52-3\\
13-3
\end{array}
\right)$ ? Does not this number represent all the possible combinations with the 52-3 cards left in the deck? 4th King included?

Comment: @auitaV: You apparently thought: choose $3$ among the $4$ kings, then take the remaining $52-3$ cards and choose $13-3=10$ among them. You do get all subsets with at least $3$ kings this way, but not all of them exactly once. In fact you get every subset containing $4$ kings in four different ways. One possibility is to correct for this over-counting. But it is not easier than counting the possibilities with $3$ and with $4$ kings separately.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen: Yes, that was exactly how I thought, I now see your point! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The possibilities for (at least) three $x$'s (where $x$ is e.g. "kings") are $4{48\choose n-3}+{48\choose n-4}$ (three kings combined with $n-3$ non-kings or all kings and $n-4$ non-kings).

Let's count how many $n$-hands there are that do *not* have three (or four) of a kind. Then all ranks occur once or twice or not at all.
For all $0\le k\le \lfloor \frac n2\rfloor$ such a hand is obtained by

- choosing $k$ out of 13 ranks to occur twice
- for each of these choose 2 out of 4
- choosing $n-2k$ of the remaining $13-k$ ranks to occur once
- for each of those choose 1 out of 4.

In total, we have
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor \frac n2\rfloor} {13\choose k}{4\choose2}^k{13-k\choose n-2k}{4\choose1}^{n-2k}=4^n\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor \frac n2\rfloor} {13\choose k}{13-k\choose n-2k}\Bigl(\frac38\Bigr)^k.$$ 
In case $n=13$ this simplifies to 
$$4^{13}\sum_{k=0}^6{13\choose k}{13-k\choose k}\Bigl(\frac38\Bigr)^k=323603221504.$$ 
Finally, we find 
$$ p = 1-{323603221504\over{52\choose 13}}\approx0.49$$

Comment: After you've chosen $k$ out of $13$ ranks, there are $13-k$ ranks that remain, not $13-2k$... This may explain the smallness of the number you found for $n=13$. And note also that for $n>13$ your summation gives $0$, which is suspect.

Comment: @Marc. Thanks for the hint. After editing, the result looks more trustworthy. Also, it is now $n>26$ instead of $n>13$ that makes avoiding 3 of a kind impossible - sounds much less suspect. :)